# Abiword document conversion output to stdout

Tags: linux, conversion, abiword

I am trying to convert documents using abiword and then would like to output the result to stdout, so that I can use that in my php application. I am able to convert, but was unable to find anything that worked to get the output to stdout, I tried this: `abiword --to=txt testfile.rtf fd://1` - this I found on: http://www.abisource.com/mailinglists/abiword-user/2009/Mar/0003.html
Its not working. any ideas? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it right:

```
abiword --to=txt --to-name=fd://1  testfile.rtf
```

Comment: Awesome thanks for the help, that works perfectly. Appreciate it.